# Getting encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" using PHP asXML and SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am using following code to get an XML file when a php page is called:

i.e. when you enter `http://example.com/strtoxmp.php`, it will return you **xml**,  based on following coding:

```
  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<feed/>");

  $feed = $xml;
  $feed->addChild('resultLength', "1");
  $feed->addChild('endIndex', "1");

  $item = $feed->addChild('item',"");
  $item->addChild('contentId', "10031");
  $item->addChild('contentType', "Talk");
  $item->addChild('synopsis', "$newTitle" );
  $item->addChild('runtime', ' ');
}

Header('Content-type: text/xml;  charset:UTF-8; ');

print($xml->asXML());
```

and it is working fine. It produces following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<feed>
<resultLength>1</resultLength>
<endIndex>1</endIndex>
<contentId>10031</contentId>
<contentType>Talk</contentType>
<synopsis>Mark Harris - Find Your Wings</synopsis>
<runtime> </runtime>
</item>
</feed>
```

But I need

> < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

instead of

> < ?xml version="1.0"?>

Comment: Who says you need that? Both should be equivalent.

Comment: ROKU does not work fine with < ?xml version="1.0"?> but it works fine with < ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>

Comment: What is ROKU? The streaming player?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To set the XML declaration, just add it to the string you pass to the SimpleXMLElement constructor:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" '
  . 'standalone="yes"?><feed/>');
```

This should output the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed/>
```

Comment: Thanks, I worked. I was shocked at the results. Can you please explain it, how it happened. Technically, what I was missing.I have tried `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>` but shown error.

Comment: Did you also add a root element when you passed that string to the constructor? If not, you wouldn't have had a valid XML document...

Comment: Just in case someone is looking for that one: If you also want to add style declarations: add something like `<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='my-xml-style.xsl' ?>` just before your `<feed/>` object. (or css style if you prefer)