# Modify XML prolog in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm reading an XML file with Simplexml and outputting a translated XML file with a different name. Google Translate outputs everything in UTF-8 and in order to properly view extended characters I need the XML Prolog to contain the encoding info:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Some files have no encoding info or even no prolog at all. 
Is there a specific method to change or add prolog info in XML files through PHP? 
Thank you.

Comment: have you tried this: [Getting encoding=“UTF-8” standalone=“yes” using PHP asXML and SimpleXMLElement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386289/getting-encoding-utf-8-standalone-yes-using-php-asxml-and-simplexmlelement) ?

Comment: I looked at that, it seems pretty easy but it's not working for me for some reason. I get a _' Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found'_ warning followed by a _Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML'._ I tried replacing < and > with &lt; and gt; to no avail. I'm sure this is basic but what am I missing?

Comment: BTW, the line of code is: 
`$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>');`

Comment: As discussed implicitly in the comment there, you need to provide a root element as well : `$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><foo/>');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, consider the following XML string with undesired XML declaration format. You can use `DOMDocument` to get only the XML content without declaration, like so :

```
$raw = '<?xml version="1.0"?><root/>';

$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($raw);
$raw_without_prolog = $xml->saveXML($xml->documentElement);
```

From this point, you can simply prepend your standard XML declaration to produce the desired XML in whatever type (plain `string`, `DOMDocument`, `SimpleXMLElement`, either one should be as easy) :

```
.....
.....
$prolog = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';

$new_xml = new DOMDocument();
$new_xml->loadXML($prolog . $raw_without_prolog);

echo $new_xml->saveXML();
```

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo`](https://eval.in/518707)</kbd>**

Comment: Thank you, I understand your approach now and it seems it's going to work. I'm a beginner in PHP and am struggling with one thing in the solution above. Attributing the prolog to the variable chokes as it probably doesn't like the `<?` and I have to escape it somehow, don't i? I tried `htmlspecialchars` but it made the `loadXML` command fail.

Comment: Update your question with the codes you tried.. the demo codes I posted also contains `<?` character and it works, so I don't know how `<?` causes problem in your case..

Comment: Thanks for the sample code, it works fine for me now.

Comment: My problem is that I was trying to load a file instead of just a string. I used your example above with load() instead of loadXML() and it worked fine.