# Why, I am getting a Fatal Error with commented $start var?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

When I use $start var like this:

```
$start = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?/>";
```

I get a fatal error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: String could not be parsed as XML in /home/users/....../test.php:6 Stack trace: #0 /home/users/....../test.php(6): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('<?xml version='...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/users/....../test.php on line 6

How can I generate nice formatted XML tag for XML?

```
$start = "<xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' />";
//$start = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?/>";

$gmXML = new SimpleXMLElement($start);
$offers = $gmXML->addChild('offers');

Header('Content-type: text/xml;');

echo $gmXML->asXML();
```

What I need is:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
```

Comment: i think you're getting confused about `<?xml` declaration and `<xml` the actual tag

Comment: See [Modify XML prolog in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35376444/modify-xml-prolog-in-php) and the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16386530/924299) about adding a root element.

Comment: Thank you guys. As Ghost wrote and I was confused about declaration and tag. Thanks for a link also!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?/>` (although with a slight mistake in it anyway) doesn't actually define an XML element as it has no root node.

With your current code, you would have to add the `<offers>` element to the XML to give it the actual element content...

```
$start = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><offers />";

$gmXML = new SimpleXMLElement($start);

Header('Content-type: text/xml;');

echo $gmXML->asXML();
```

Also note the end of the definition is `?>` and not `?/>`

As your other version of the XML...

```
$start = "<xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' />";
```

This actually declares a root node called `<xml>`.

Comment: In case anyone thinks the `<xml />` form might be useful in some way, it's worth noting that `xml` and anything beginning `xml` is a reserved name in the XML spec, so should never be used.