# PHP: Make sure that a XML files is save as UFT-8

Tags: php, xml

I have these lines of PHP code which save a XML file. It works fine. I just need to make sure that the saved file uses Encoding UFT-8.

Problem is that the file is not saved as Encoding UFT-8 and since this file is used for an import process I get the import to run with some issues.

That is why I need to make sure the file is saved a UFT-8.

```
$newXml = $myXmlContent;
$newXml = simplexml_load_string( $newXml );
//... here a line of code to force this file to use Encoding UFT-8 //
$newXml->asXml('/home/example/www/myXmlFile.xml');
```

Just in case, this file is regenerated every day, that's why saving the file as UFT-8 using Notepad (or similar) will not solved my problem.

Comment: Please elaborate more your problem. I

Comment: Does the original XML file contain the encoding="UTF-8" attribute? Is the original content in UTF-8?

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386289/getting-encoding-utf-8-standalone-yes-using-php-asxml-and-simplexmlelement/16386530

Comment: @Progman yes. Both files start with <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>